# How do I change the volume of Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am working on a project that receives information from an Atmel board using python, and I needed to change the chrome browser volume. I am trying to use selenium but I only found how to mute Chrome.

Comment: Does Chrome have a volume setting?  That seems like a system setting.  Maybe there's something specific in chrome://settings that I don't know about?  If you can pin point that, then there's a chance you can set it with Selenium, but if it's outside the browser, it might not be possible.

Comment: Try looking at ActionChains along with Keys in Selenium. If your volume can be changed by clicking a function key on your keyboard, it might work: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys

Answer (score 4):

You do not need selenium to do it. 
You need pycaw to control the volume of the application running on your system, here is an example of how to do it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, ISimpleAudioVolume


sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
for session in sessions:
    volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(ISimpleAudioVolume)
    if session.Process and session.Process.name() == "chrome.exe":
        volume.SetMasterVolume(0.5, None)
```